# MobileConnect Contacts Import Doesn't update Contacts' Status (Opted Out => Opted In)

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, contactbuilder, data-import, status

How can we change contacts' status from Opted Out To Opted In using Import? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to resubscribe an opted-out contact with an import definition.

The only way this could be achieved right now seems to be an API call executed to the API of Marketing Cloud from a script activity using this endpoint: [PATCH /contacts/v1/contacts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateContacts.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried using that call but I don't know what's the name of the status attribute and value within the API request. does it look like this?:
"Status" : "Opted In"

Comment: Also you can use messageContact APIcall to resubscribe contact. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm

Use empty ampscript (%%[]%%) to prevent message from sending